# How transaction manipulation handles in Blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I'm new to Blockchain and would like to understand few concepts in a detail. 
After reading about basics of Blockchain, one thing is unclear to me about tx. manipulation.

For instance, A has some (i.e: $10) money and A is sending half($5) of it to B.
but C manipulate that transaction before going to Blockchain and set $10 instead.

Now, A wanted to send only $5, but some how A's account will get empty since miner will check A has enough balance or not.

How Blokchain resolves this type of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, A has some (i.e: $10) money and A is sending half($5) of it to B. but C manipulate that transaction before going to Blockchain and set $10 instead.

This is not possible, provided the original transaction is signed correctly. In a regular transaction, you sign the inputs and the outputs. If someone changes the input or output amount, the signature is invalid, and the transaction will not be mined.